# Re-reading and updating supervisord on elastic beanstalk workers

Tags: amazon-web-services, supervisord

I have recently set up a worker tier on AWS Elastic Beanstalk to run a scheduler and some workers (Using RQ). In my deployment, I copy a bunch of configuration files into `/opt/python/etc/` so that my `supervisord.conf` can include them to run the processes. This all works fine. To start all the processes I need to `reread` and `update` supervisord however when I do this, the command succeeds in my deployment and then I lose connectivity a few seconds later.

The relevant part of my `.ebextensions` config is:

```
03_config_supervisor_confs_and_logs:
  command: "mkdir -p /var/log/redis/ && cp supervisord/*.conf /opt/python/etc/"
04_update_supervisor:
  command: "supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf reread && supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf update"
```

I have ensured it is the final step causing the issue as I have been able to deploy fine without step `04_update_supervisor` and then ssh into the instance and run the command manually, again it runs fine and then I lose connectivity shortly after.

Answer (score 2):

[.ebextensions config has multiple sections](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-files), you are running some host or container commands that are perhaps executing too early.  You may want to consider using the "files" section and adding files to run these commands in `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post`, this will delay the execution of these commands until later in the deployment process i.e.

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/04_update_supervisor.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf reread && supervisorctl -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf update
```